# Flex3 app: Audio Only FLV don't play correctly

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, red5

I got a flex3 app and a red5 0.63 server.

My app plays audio only flv files stored in the server, but don't play correctly.

It plays some milliseconds, and stops. It receives the metadata, the seekbar length is correct. When I try to seek, it goes back to the beginning and plays the same few milliseconds.

Comment: Have you tested the flv outside your app to be sure it's not broken? Just a guess, but I'd look at the logic your player's using to decide when it's reached the end of a file it's playing. You might want to give more information about your component structure, and the code that's supposed to run the playing of the flv.

Comment: I updated to 0.8 (because the latest have a ns.send bug). When I play with VLC it is almost good (some seekbar weirdness). I noticed that when there is no sound in the file it is not played correctly by Flex/Red5.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and used this:

```
microphone.setSilenceLevel(0, 0);
```

I guess Red5 needs noise..